# Laravel: Undefined Variable in View when sending mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Upon trying to create a mail view and passing variables to it, I ran into this error:

Undefined variable: username (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/app/views/emails/auth/activate.blade.php)

Here is my Blade View that has the undefined var:

```
Hello {{ $username }},

Please activate your account using the following link

{{ $link }}
```

and here is my controller:

```
<?php
class AccountController extends BaseController {

public function getCreate() {
    return View::make('account.create');
}

//Validation
public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'email' => 'required | max:50 | email | unique:users',
            'username' => 'required | max:20 | min:3 | unique:users',
            'password' => 'required | min:6',
            'password_again' => 'required | same:password'
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('account-create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    } else {
        //Create Account
        $email  = Input::get('email');
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');

        //Activation Code

        $code = str_random(60);

        $user = User::create (array(
                'email'=> $email,
                'username'=> $username,
                'password'=> Hash::make($password),
                'code'=> $code,
                'active'=> 0
        ));

        if ($user) {

                //Sending email
                Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), 'username' => $username), function ($message) use ($user) {
                        $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Activate Your Account');
                });

                return Redirect::route('home')
                        ->with('global', 'Check your inbox for your conformation!');
        }
    }
}

public function getActivate($code) {
        return $code;
}
```

}

I am new to Laravel and PHP and I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score -2):

I found the mistake! I was calling the view from my HomeController and not defining the vars there